# Executing a program gives No such file or folder error

Tags: linux, shell, executable, binary

I can't execute a simple executable.

The result of `ll`

```
user@user-SATELLITE-C855-169:~/Bureau/Workspace/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin$ ll
total 16948
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user    4096 avril 18  2014 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 user user    4096 janv. 18 21:01 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  565152 avril 18  2014 armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-addr2line*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 user user  589764 avril 18  2014 armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 user user 1035780 avril 18  2014 armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-as*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 user user  624784 avril 18  2014 armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-c++*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user      28 avril 18  2014 armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-cc -> armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-gcc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  563424 avril 18  2014 armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-c++filt*
```

and this is how I execute `armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar`

```
user@user-SATELLITE-C855-169:~/Bureau/Workspace/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin$ ./armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar
```

This gives

```
No such file or folder
```

What is meant by the * in the end of each file -- is there something special?

**EDIT**

Propsed manip by @Arkadiusz Drabczyk:

```
user@user-SATELLITE-C855-169:~/Bureau/Workspace/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin$ readelf -a armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar | grep "Requesting program interpreter:"
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

Propsed manip by @steeldriver:

```
user@user-SATELLITE-C855-169:~/Bureau/Workspace/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin$ arch
x86_64
```

I am using a 64 bit OS.

```
user@user-SATELLITE-C855-169:~/Bureau/Workspace/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin$ file armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar
armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=8dac66869f5be2dbb2bee517e289901c4be80db5, stripped
```

The binary seems to work with a 32 bit architecture `ELF 32-bit`.

Comment: Is `armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar` a script? If it is, does the first line of the script (with `#!`) point to an interpreter that actually exists?

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks no it's not a script it's an executable.

Comment: The `ll` command that you use is an alias for `ls` with some flags.  One of the flags is probably `-F`, which adds `*` to any executable file in the listing.

Comment: Yes it seems the star come from there

Comment: Is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit? does the binary you are trying to run have the same architecture (what does `file armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar` say)?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, seems this is the problem i edit the question with manip you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any help, what is meant by the * in the end of each file is there sth
>   special?

Your `ll` alias may contain `-F` option which adds a character after a file name. From `man ls`:

```
   -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

In many shells such as `bash` you can check how an alias is expanded using `type` command. For example, on my system:

`$ type ll
ll is aliased to 'ls -Alhtr --color'`

Now, you said that the file that gives you the error is a binary so it may be due to an incorrect loader. Try what loader it requests and make sure you have it:

```
$ readelf -a armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar | grep "Requesting program interpreter:"
```

If the binary is designated to run on `x32` system it will request a `x32` interpreter from `/lib`. If you don't have it will not start. So now, depending on the system you use you need to find a way to add 32-bit compatibility layer to your system. For example, on `Ubuntu` it's simple - just a single `apt-get install` will do the job, for `Slackware` it's described here: http://docs.slackware.com/slackware:multilib .

Comment: ok thanks i undrestand the meaning of * , however i can't undrestand why when i execute the binary `./armv5-ctng-linux-gnueabi-ar` i'am getting `no such file or directory`

Comment: I edit the question this gives `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`

Comment: ok, so do you have `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`? Show output of: `ll /lib/ld-linux.so.2`.

Comment: no i don't have.

Comment: well, that's your problem. As suggested in the comments by user [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) you're probably running x64 operating system and you don't have x32 compatibility layer. Please post output of `uname -m` command. Do you have `/lib` directory at all? Do you have `/lib64`?

Comment: yes it seems this is the problem my OS is 64 bit however the binary is 32 bits i edit the question. I do have /lib64 and /lib

Comment: ok, so now, depending on the system you use you need to find a way to add 32-bit compatibility layer to your system. For example, on `Ubuntu` it's simple - just a single `apt-get install` will do the job, for `Slackware` it's described here: https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:multilib

Comment: OK, thank u very much i will install and update the status, Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok. If you like this answer please mark it as accepted so that other users will know it's solved.

Comment: OK just update your answer with the last comment